# Outlier detection in discrete signals

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, signals, signal-processing, outliers

I have a discrete signal of value 0,1,2,3 that shall look like this in ideal case:

[image]

but it reality it looks like this most of the times:

[image]

so to detect these outliers I used a rolling median in pandas, dfResult dataframe contains 511 values equal either to 0,1,2,3, in predicted columns.

```
from pandas.core.window import Rolling
threshold = 1
dfResult['median'] = dfResult['predicted'].rolling(10).median()
difference = np.abs(dfResult['predicted'] - dfResult['median'])
outlier_idx = difference > threshold
```

Now when it is detecting wrong outliers along with correct ones as seen below:
[image]

now how I could remove these wrong outliers which are shown after 300 ticks. Any redirection/blogs to checking outliers in discrete signals will be much appreciated. I do not need to detect outliers in real-time, I only have to do post processing.

sample data:

```
dfResult['predicted'].values
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Could you please share some small data?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Did the solution proposed not do what you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I will go about it:
`window` can be used to select the width of outlier.

```
window = 2

#Indices of change
diff_ind = df.data.diff()[df.data.diff()!=0].index
diff_ind = pd.DataFrame({'diff_ind':diff_ind})
outlier_ind = df_diff_ind.diff_ind[df_diff_ind.diff_ind.diff() < window]
```

`outlier_ind.values` will have `array([ 26, 251, 252], dtype=int64)` which are the indices of values you refer to as outliers.

You can do whatever you feel fit with these :)

Hope this helps.